# Using .htaccess to rewrite a simple url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url like this - www.example.com/blog.php/username, it will take you to the username's blog page, but I want to use a url like this instead - www.example.com/blog/username to get to the same file (blog.php). Please what are the steps I need to take to achieve this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: you using any framework?

Comment: What's wrong with the site search?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect using username in URL with .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861469/redirect-using-username-in-url-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htacess. Then add this code in your .htaccess under DOCUMENT_ROOT:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# If the request is not for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
# finally this is your rewrite rule
RewriteRule ^blog/(.+)$ blog.php/$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a file in your root direstory named .htaccess and past this in :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule     ^blog/(.*)$     yourpage.php?username=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

(.*) will take any caracters
If you want to use only letters and numbers change `(.*)` by `([A-Za-z0-9])`

Answer (score 1):

Removing file extension:

> There are two ways to do this. The easy way which just looks at a
>   request, if the requested filename doesn't exist, then it looks for
>   the filename with a .php (or .asp or whatever) extension. In an
>   .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

> Now if you go to: http://domain/about the server will interpret it as
>   if you went to http://domain/about.php.
>
> Makes sense, but if we're already breaking the relation between URL
>   and filename, we may as well break it intelligently. Change that
>   .htaccess file:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Source: Dave Dash -> http://davedash.com/2006/07/26/how-to-remove-file-extensions-from-urls/

Answer (score 1):

1 You should install mod-rewrite

2 You should make sure that for your doc root directory is "AllowOverride All". Ordinary after virtualhost configuration you should find something like:

```
<Directory "/your/doc/root/path/">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

3 After that you should start rewrite engine and create rewrite rule in your .htaccess as David Bélanger advises:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule     ^blog/(.*)$     blog.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```